# TTL for system.query_log is not set (clickhouse)

Tags: clickhouse

when I use `<engine>` tag to set ttl for query_log table in config.xml file - ttl is set for new table query_log after removing old one:

```
<query_log>
    <database>system</database>
    <table>query_log</table>
    <engine>ENGINE = MergeTree PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(event_date)
        ORDER BY (event_date, event_time)
        TTL event_date + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE DELETE
        SETTINGS min_bytes_for_wide_part = '10M'
    </engine>
    <flush_interval_milliseconds>7500</flush_interval_milliseconds>
</query_log>
```

but when I want to configure ttl in a separate tag `<ttl>` - ttl doesn't set for new query_log table:

```
<query_log>
    <database>system</database>
    <table>query_log</table>
    <partition_by>toYYYYMM(event_date)</partition_by>
    <ttl>event_date + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE DELETE</ttl>
    <flush_interval_milliseconds>7500</flush_interval_milliseconds>
</query_log>
```

I use clickhouse 20.8.2.3

Can someone help me to solve this problem, please? I want to use **`<ttl>`** option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20.8.2.3 is out support.

You need to upgrade.

*https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#clickhouse-release-v211215-stable-2021-01-18*

*ClickHouse release v21.1.2.15-stable 2021-01-18*

*Allow specifying TTL to remove old entries from system log tables, using the `<ttl>` attribute in config.xml. #17438 (Du Chuan).*

Comment: tried this, originally I didnt had this configuration, so the number of records gained with the time, now that I have added this, clickhouse has created another query_log table with ttl enabled, and has renamed the older table as query_log_0, to reclaim the disk space, should we manually truncate the records from query_log_0 table or clickhouse will do it for me?

Comment: you can drop or truncate it. Up to you. Clickhouse never uses _log tables. https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/altinity-kb-system-tables-eat-my-disk/